# Почему массив $_GET не меняется?

Tags: php, get

Есть такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
     echo $_GET;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Результат вывода - пустой массив. Так и должно быть, но дальше я пытаюсь в адресе прописать ключ и значение.

Т.е. в адресную строку прописываю такого рода строку:

```
http://test.loc/index.php?id=3
```

(Это локальный сервер). Но от этого результат вывода не меняется. Т.е. в массиве не появляется ключ `'id'`.

В чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Команда `echo` не покажет вам массив, вы должны его перебрать через `foreach` либо вывести через `print_r`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Команда `echo` не покажет вам массив, вы должны его перебрать через `foreach` либо вывести через `print_r`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
       $get = $_GET; // лучше сразу забрать перемунную с глобального массива $_GET и работать со своей переменной
       
       // если нужно вывести в html название переменной со значением
       foreach ($get as $key => $value) {
          echo "Вы передали перемунную $key со значением $value <br/>";
       }
       
       // если просто проверить что данные пришли методом GET
       print_r($get);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```